# Error on Anaconda 5.3 while installing RStudio , saying offline mode

Tags: anaconda, rstudio

I downloaded Anaconda 5.3 and am trying to Install RStudio in it. I get the below error always after upgrading.

*"Some of the functionality of Anaconda Navigator will be limited in offline mode."
"Installation and upgrade of packages will be subject to the packages currently available on your package cache."*

Even if the internet is connected, I get the same error which didnt happen with previous version. Does anyone know how to overcome this? Please advise.

Btw, RCran and RStudio are not approved software and hence I am trying to use the one through Anaconda IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as you here, there is an issue related https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10176.

While anaconda-navigator having this problem, you can still install packages through anaconda prompt.

1. open anaconda prompt in your start menu
2. type `conda install rstudio`